Send-MailMessage gives error "net_io_connectionclosed"
I have a PowerShell script that checks for a condition periodically and I want it to send an email if the condition occurs. I'm having trouble with the email part of this. All of the systems involved are Server 2019 and members of our Active Directory domain. The SMTP server I'm sending to is an internal SMTP relay server. It is already working/relaying email for other network clients. I separated the Send-MailMessage part of my script to test and get the syntax working. Here is the syntax that works for the first Server 2019 system I tested on:
$local = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$MailMessage = @{
To = "my_Email"
From = "noreply@domain"
Subject = "Testing SMTP from PowerShell - $local@domain"
Body = "Testing sending mail via powershell for scripting."
Smtpserver = "SMTP_Relay_Server"
Port = 25
UseSsl = $true
Encoding = “UTF8”
Priority = "High"
}

Send-MailMessage @MailMessage 

When I take it to another Server 2019, in the same domain, same subnet, same patch level, I get the following error:
Send-MailMessage : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
At line:18 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage @MailMessage
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

On the SMTP server side, when this error occurs, it sees the SMTP traffic in Wireshark. But it says "NO_DATA (23)" in the TCP section.
When researching this error, it seems like an error people got when one of the systems involved (either the sending system or the receiving SMTP) was older and there was a mismatch of TLS versions. But I don't understand why that would be. Nevertheless, I checked the TLS settings on the server that worked by running this:
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol

And the output is:
Tls, Tls11, Tls12

I run the same thing on the server that is giving the error and the output matches.
I've rebooted the server twice. Still the same thing. Any assistance fixing this would be greatly appreciated.
Update: On the system giving the error, I commented out the "-UseSSL" parameter and tested. I still get the same error. So maybe it doesn't have anything to do with TLS. But I cannot find anything related to the error that I'm getting that does not have to do with TLS.
